# Removing folders from windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

Can i remove any of these? This is for another computer that does not have internet at all...ever, if this makes a difference

```
Microsoft ActiveSync
windows mail
windows journal
C:\captures
C:\EFI
C:\kiosk
C:\netgear
C:\PerfLogs
C:\uploads
```

Comment: Everything except the EFI directory is user created.

Comment: Also, PerfLogs is system-created and best left alone. What's the full path of the first 3 folders?

Comment: While PerfLogs is system created its created through user action and safe to delete

Answer (score 0):

Few of those directories are necessary for your PC. PerfLogs, if deleted, will automatically be re-created so don't bother wirth that one. And don't remove the EFI folder either, as it refers to the UEFI boot system.

Comment: Stating that none of the directories are necessary and then, at the very end, stating that EFI shouldn't be deleted (thereby implying that it is actually essential) is not a very clear answer. You have also got the name of PerfLogs wrong.